Trouble with counting to invert relationship between two sets of tensors
I am working through understanding a paper and among its calculations are two sets of tensors $\lbrace J_n \rbrace$ and $\lbrace I_n\rbrace$ over the same vector space. The components of these tensors I will write $J_n^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\mu\sigma\nu}$ and $I_{n}^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n\mu\nu}$ with $n \in \lbrace 0,1,2,3,...\rbrace$ indicating which element of the respective set is considered and the Greek letters being component indices.
The $\lbrace J_n \rbrace$ are defined in terms of the $\lbrace I_n \rbrace$ and the $\lbrace I_n \rbrace$ have several index interchange symmetries. In particular:
\begin{gather}
I^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n\mu\nu}_n = I^{(\kappa_1...\kappa_n)(\mu\nu)}_n
\end{gather}
\begin{gather}
I^{(\kappa_1...\kappa_n\mu)\nu}_n = 0
\end{gather}
\begin{gather}
J^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\mu\sigma\nu}_n  = \frac{1}{4}(I^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma\mu\nu}_{n+2} - I^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n\mu\sigma\rho\nu}_{n+2} - I_{n+2}^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\nu\mu\sigma} + I_{n+2}^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n\mu\nu\rho\sigma}).
\end{gather}
Indices enclosed in parentheses are symmetrized so that in the components of a tensor with $N$ indices enclosed, the symmetrized object is $\frac{1}{N!}$ times the sum over the tensor components in each possible permutation of the $N$ indices. The paper says that given these conditions, the $\lbrace I_n \rbrace$ coefficients for $n > 1$ can be completely recovered from the $\lbrace J_n \rbrace$ coefficients by the formula:
\begin{gather}
  I_n^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n\mu\nu} = \frac{4(n-1)}{n+1} J^{(\kappa_1...\kappa_{n-1}|\mu|\kappa_n)\nu}_{n-2}
 \end{gather}
where $\mu$ being enclosed in bars as $|\mu|$ indicates it is not to be symmetrized over by the surrounding parentheses.
I am having trouble justifying this last equation. I expect it is quite simple, but have not found a calculation that works.
By directly applying the suggested symmetrization to the definition of $J_{n}^{\cdots}$, I find (using the first symmetry equation for $I_n^\cdots$)
\begin{gather}
4 J_{n}^{(\kappa_1...\kappa_{n}\rho|\mu|\sigma)\nu} = I_{n+2}^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma\mu\nu} - I_{n+2}^{\mu(\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)\nu} - I_{n+2}^{\nu(\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)\mu} + I_{n+2}^{\mu\nu(\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)}.
\end{gather}
The first term on the right needs no simplification, the second and third of the same form and I can simplify nicely, the fourth is where I am stuck.
For the second term (using the second index symmetry condition on $I_n^{\cdots}$:
\begin{gather}
0 = (n+3)I_{n+2}^{(\mu\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)\nu} = I_{n+2}^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma\mu\nu} + (n+2) I_{n+2}^{\mu(\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)\nu} \\
\implies I_{n+2}^{\mu(\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)\nu} = -\frac{1}{n+2}I_{n+2}^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n \rho\sigma\mu\nu}
\end{gather}
which is now in the desired form. The third term is also equal to this, by the same argument.
I suspect there is an equally simple symmetrization to perform on the fourth term, but I haven't seen it. Any suggestions?

I figured out the answer myself with enough fiddling.
There are $(n+4)!$ terms in $I_{n+2}^{(\mu\nu\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)}$. These terms can be organized into $n+4$ sets of $(n+3)!$ terms, each of which have one of the indices $\mu,\nu\kappa_1...\kappa_n,\rho,\sigma$ in the final slot and the other $n+3$ terms taking each possible ordering once each. Each of these collections then add to 0 individually, by the second condition on $I_{n}^\cdots$. Thus:
\begin{gather}
I_{n+2}^{(\mu\nu\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)} = 0.
\end{gather}
Alternatively, this same collection of $(n+4)!$ terms can be organized into $(n+2)(n+3)!$ terms which have $\mu$ not in any of the last two slots and $2 (n+3)!$ terms which have $\mu$ in the last two slots. Using the first condition on $I_n^{\cdots}$ and canceling shared factors gives:
\begin{gather}
(n+4) I_{n+2}^{(\mu\nu\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)} = (n+2) I^{\mu(\nu\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)}_{n+2} + 2 I_{n+2}^{(\nu\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)\mu}.
\end{gather}
The left hand side is 0 by the previous deduction, and the second term on the right hand side is 0 by the second condition on $I_n^\cdots$. Thus, the remaining term on the right hand side is also 0:
\begin{gather}
I^{\mu(\nu\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)}_{n+2} = 0. 
\end{gather}
This expression can be expanded into $(n+3)!$ terms, and among them there are $(n+1)(n+2)!$ terms in which $\nu$ does not appear in the last two slots and $2(n+2)!$ terms in which $\nu$ does appear in the last two slots. Again canceling shared combinatorial factors:
\begin{gather}
(n+3)I^{\mu(\nu\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)} = (n+1) I^{\mu\nu(\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)} + 2 I^{\mu(\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)\nu}.
\end{gather}
The left hand side is 0 and the second term on the right hand side was previously computed. Together this yields:
\begin{gather}
I^{\mu\nu(\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma)} = \frac{2}{(n+1)(n+2)}I_{n+2}^{\kappa_1...\kappa_n\rho\sigma\mu\nu}.
\end{gather}
When returned to the calculation involving $J_n^\cdots$ this results in the desired final expression.
